# The latest inserted key into std::map cannot be found

Tags: c++, oop, std, stdmap

My problem is that whatever the very last element I insert into the `std::map`, I will not be able to find it.

I have the following map that takes Color as a key and encodes it to some object type (enum).

```
class ColorEncoder {
private:
    std::map<Color, Object::Type> validObjects;

public:
    ColorEncoder() {
        load(Color(76, 177, 34), Object::Player);
        load(Color(36, 28, 237), Object::Block);
     // load(Color(0, 111, 222), Object::PleaseDont); // uncomment this line and everything will work correctly,
                                                      // but the map will have one garbage value
    }

    void load(Color color, Object::Type type) {
        validObjects.insert(std::make_pair(color, type));
    }

    auto& getValidObjects() {
        return validObjects;
    }
};
```

I also have an `array` of Colors. The goal is to verify whether each array element does indeed exist in the map.

Hence, I am iterating over the array, and each time checking if current array element does exist as a key in the map:

```
class BMP_Analyzer {
public:
    // assume data size is 12
    BMP_Analyzer(std::unique_ptr<Color[]>& data, std::map<Color, Object::Type>& validObjects) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            if (validObjects.find(data[i]) == validObjects.end()) {
                std::cout << "Not found in the map!\t";
                std::cout << "Blue: " << (uint16_t) data[i].blue << " " << " Green: "
                          << (uint16_t) data[i].green << " Red: " << (uint16_t) data[i].red
                          << " is not mapped!" << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Exemplary output:

```
Not found in the map!   Blue: 36  Green: 28 Red: 237 is not mapped!
Not found in the map!   Blue: 36  Green: 28 Red: 237 is not mapped!
```

However if I uncomment this:

```
// load(Color(0, 111, 222), Object::PleaseDont);
```

Then it will correctly detect the above previously not found color: `(36, 28, 237)`.

It looks like off-by-one or something to me, but honestly I have no idea where is the potential mistake.

Color is defined as follows, with overloaded `operator<` so it can work as a key with `std::map`.

```
struct Color {
    uint8_t blue;
    uint8_t green;
    uint8_t red;

    Color() = default;

    Color(uint8_t blue, uint8_t green, uint8_t red)
        :blue{blue},
         green{green},
         red{red}
    {
    }

    bool operator<(const Color& other) const {
        return blue != other.blue || green != other.green || red != other.red;
    }
}
```

Any hints where the problem can lie are very welcomed, thanks.

Comment: Your comparison operator isn’t defining a *strict, weak order*. Thus, your use of the type in a `std::map` results in indefined behavior.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The comparison of keys in a `st::map` has to be a *strict, weak order*, i.e., the following rules have to hold:

1. `(a < a) == false`
2. `(a < b) == true && (b < c) == true` implies `(a < c) == true`
3. `(a < b) == true` implies `(b < a) == false`
4. `(a < b) == false && (b < a) == false) && (b < c) == false && (c < b) == false)` implies `(a < c) && (c < a) == false`

The easiest way to achieve that for a structure is to leverage `std::tuple`s comparison:

```
bool operator< (Color const& c0, Color const& c1) {
    return std::tie(c0.blue, c0.green, c0.red) < std::tie(c1.blue, c1.green, c1.red);
}
```

This comparison operator actually defines a stronger order: a total order.